# How to call method from CS page using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asmx

I want to call the method which is in CS page using AJAX.

Here is my design code:

```
<!-- Name -->
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" class="form" placeholder="Name" />
<!-- Email -->
<input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" required="required" class="form" placeholder="Email" />
<!-- Subject -->
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required="required" class="form" placeholder="Subject" />
<!-- Message -->
<textarea name="message" id="message" class="form textarea" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<!-- Send Button -->
<button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="form-btn semibold">Send Message</button>
```

Here is the ajax

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function (e) {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "OakscrollWebService.cs/SendMail",
         dataType: "json",
         data: JSON.stringify({ name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#mail').val(), subject: $('#subject').val(), message: $('#message').val() }),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data) {
             alert(data.d);
         },
         failure: function (data) {
             alert("something went wrong");
             //console.log(msg);
         }
     });
 });
```

Now, I add the asmx page (web service). In that I have given the reference call to the CS file which is in App_Code folder, here is the code.

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/OakscrollWebService.cs" Class="OakscrollWebService" %>
```

Here the cs file from where I want to call the SendMail method using ajax (which code I shown you previously) and here is the method code in cs file

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendMail(string name, string email, string subject, string message)
{
    //Thread.Sleep(10000);
    // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
    var fromAddress = "mextra03@gmail.com";
    // any address where the email will be sending
    var toAddress = email.Trim();
    //Password of your gmail address
    const string fromPassword = "*********";
    // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
    string sub = subject.Trim();
    string body = "From: " + name.Trim() + "\n";
    body += "Email: " + email.Trim() + "\n";
    body += "Subject: " + subject.Trim() + "\n";
    body += "Message: \n" + message.Trim() + "\n";
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, sub, body);
}
```

This is the content I used to call the sendmail method by ajax. But facing issues like "403 forbidden" and "500 server not found" and can't call the sendmail method using AJAX.

Comment: Is the debugger hitting `SendMail` cs code on ajax call? Check that once. Also, put a `try { ... } catch() { ... }` inside the cs code to check if there is any smtp or general exceptions in the code.

Comment: no sendmail method is not getting debug. I put debug on it but not getting call.

Comment: How did you go with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you need to change your url to have the file extension `.asmx` instead of `.cs` (change the line `url: "OakscrollWebService.cs/SendMail",` to `url: "OakscrollWebService.asmx/SendMail",`) because when I tested it I was getting a 404 error meaning the page was not found. You could also create a variable to check that your JSON is correct using [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/).

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function (e) {
      var data = '{"name":"' + $('#name').val() + '", "email":"' + $('#mail').val() + '", "subject":"' + $('#subject').val() + '", "message":"' + $('#message').val() + '"}'; //Optional to check your JSON
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "OakscrollWebService.asmx/SendMail",
             dataType: "json",
             data: JSON.stringify({ name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#mail').val(), subject: $('#subject').val(), message: $('#message').val() }),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function (data) {
                 alert(data.d);
             },
             failure: function (data) {
                 alert("something went wrong");
                 //console.log(msg);
             }
         });
     });
  });
```

Good luck!